# Linux: how to dump audio output PCM bit stream like tcpdump

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pcm

I am trying to do some audio debugging on my Linux system.

I learned how to record the sound of the current playing media but how can I get the PCM data without DAC/ADC?

I mean, just like **wireshark** or **tcpdump** tool, is there some sort of ***alsadump*** that I can make use of?

I want to do bit-exact comparison of the output PCM data to make sure the audio processing algorithm (which is an executable binary) worked correctly.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're using Pulse, there's a useful discussion here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/60837/record-a-programs-output-with-pulseaudio. For raw ALSA, see this: http://hansekbrand.se/code/recording-audio-streams.html. In either case, it's kind of fiddly.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried the alsa solution to add a .asoundrc file but nothing happened after I played an audio clip with aplay. What could be go wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. I'd guess that you're intercepting the wrong ALSA channel but, unless I were sitting in front of your machine, I don't think there's a way to be sure. Good luck.